# Which open source scrum tool to choose?

Tags: scrum

We are searching an open source scrum agile tool which can help us to do the reporting and   manage our agile developments.
We need your help to find and choose the best tools

Answer (score 3):

**Here is the tool which will help you.**

---

Agilefant.
1.Using this you can add your sprints. 
2.You can assign tasks to particular user.
3.You can see the graph according to the hours spent by users.
4.Sprint backlogs also can carry in next sprint.

---

here is the link http://agilefant.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response ,Agilefant seems to be helpfull

Comment: if you find it helpfull then accept the answer and mark as right